# Breaking Bad special episodes

Tags: breaking-bad

I got all five seasons of Breaking Bad. I use [Series Guide](http://seriesgui.de/) to see what to watch next. [The special episodes](https://trakt.tv/show/breaking-bad/specials) are missing, I want to get them but first I have few question about them.

- Special 1 Good Cop Bad Cop
- Special 2 Wedding Day
- Special 3 TwaughtHammer
- Special 4 Marie's Confession
- Special 5 The Break-In
- **Special 6 Season 4 Sneak Peak**
- **Special 8 Better Call Saul - Carl B.**
- Special 9 Better Call Saul - Saul Better Help My Mom
- Special 10 Better Call Saul - Badger
- Special 11 Better Call Saul - Tiger Trouble
- Special 12 Better Call Saul - Wayfarer 515
- Special 13 Team S.C.I.E.N.C.E
- Special 14 Better Call Saul - Wendy
- Special 15 Better Call Saul - Who Can You Sue
- Special 16 Letters to Saul - Did I Murder an Old Man
- Special 17 Live Saul Cam
- Special 18 No Half Measures

---

- Is there 18 special episodes or 17? If there's 18, what is special episode 7?
- when to watch these special episodes? after you finish everything? Or are they similar to 24 special episodes where you have to watch them first to understand what going to happen next? Can you tell me when exactly is the best time to watch these episodes?
- Why not all episodes are [listed  on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Breaking_Bad_episodes)? Like Episode 18

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AMC, the creators of Breaking Bad, released the first **five** webisodes in the build up to Season 2. They were eventually released on the Season 2 boxset.

So you can watch Specials 1 - 5 as soon as you finish Season 1.

As for the rest of your list, I suspect the episode 7 gap is simply an oversight (and one that has been copied by other sites, e.g. [here](http://thetvdb.com/?tab=season&seriesid=81189&seasonid=439371&lid=7)). The best source for this information would be AMC themselves. They list the episodes [here](http://www.amctv.com/shows/breaking-bad/tag/videotype/minisode), in no obvious order.

Users online have *attempted* to state their correct order. [This user on TheTVDB.com](http://forums.thetvdb.com/viewtopic.php?t=11274) stated the order was:

> 01 - Better Call Saul -  Carl B.
>   02 - Better Call Saul -  Saul Better
>   Help My Mom
>   03 - Better Call Saul - Badger
>   04 - Better Call Saul -
>   Tiger Trouble
>   05 - Better Call Saul - Wayfarer 515
>   06 - Team
>   S.C.I.E.N.C.E.
>   07 - Better Call Saul - Wendy
>   08 - Better Call Saul -
>   Who Can You Sue
>   09 - Letters to Saul - Did I Murder an Old Man
>   10 -
>   Live Saul Cam

[IMDB on the other hand](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2387761/episodes?season=2&ref_=tt_eps_sn_2) have a totally different order listed (along with different episode titles!). Despite this, the order pasted above appears to be the most consistently quoted order (matching the one you posted).

I did come across quite a few torrent sites online with the series listed and the episodes all listed in the order pasted above as part of the Season 3 extras (that is, released after Season 2 and before Season 3). This would suit the timeline listed for them (2010).

Therefore, I would conclude this:

- There is no episode 7. That's simply a mistake that has been copied in quite a few places. Or rather, there is an episode 7, but the gap suggesting there isn't is a mistake.
- Watch Specials 1 - 5 after Season 1.
- Watch Specials in order pasted above after Season 2.
- Watch Season 4 Sneak Peek after Season 3.
- I'm not sure *why* these episodes aren't more recognised (I didn't even know they existed until this question). It seems particularly strange given that [Better Call Saul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul) is now in confirmed production.